# Error importing tensorflow , tensorflow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine

Tags: tensorflow

**System information**

### -  Linux Ubuntu 16.04

- TensorFlow installed from binary (pip install)
- TensorFlow version:
- Python version: 3.5
- Installed using virtualenv? pip? conda?: pip and virtualenv
- Bazel version (if compiling from source):
- GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source):
- CUDA/cuDNN version:
- GPU model and memory:

**Problem described**

i was following the tutorial for using intel neural stick 2 for object detection https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-up-predictions-on-low-power-devices-using-neural-compute-stick-and-openvino-98f3ae9dcf41
in the  example i install the prerequisites using the command 
`sudo ./opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites/install_prerequisites.sh`

tensorflow was installed with the prerequisites , i also installed tensorflow using pip install , but when i run the next command

`mo_tf.py \
    --input_model ~/Downloads/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/frozen_inference_graph.pb \
    --tensorflow_use_custom_operations_config     /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/extensions/front/tf/ssd_support.json \
    --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config ~/Downloads/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/pipeline.config \
    --data_type FP16`

i get the following error 
`F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] 
The tensorflow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available in your machine 
Aborted (core dumped)`

i am getting the same error when try and **import tensorflow**

what should i do to solve this error ?

Comment: This might be a better question for superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the machine does not support avx. Is it so? You can refer this link [How to tell if a Linux machine supports AVX/AVX2 instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480071/how-to-tell-if-a-linux-machine-supports-avx-avx2-instructions) to check the same.

If your machine does not support AVX, then the solution would be to build tensorflow from source excluding those settings