# FAISS search fails with vague error: "Illegal instruction" or kernel crash

Tags: python-3.x, similarity, cosine-similarity, wsl-2

Currently trying to run a basic similarity search via [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/Getting-started) with reproducible code from that link.  However, every time I run the code in the following venues, I have these problems:

- Jupyter notebook - kernel crashes
- VS Code - receive "Illegal Instruction" message in the terminal with no further documentation

I've got similar code working in Kaggle, so I suppose the problem is with my particular setup.

Based on the print statements, it appears that the error occurs during the call of the `.search` method.  Because of how vague this error is, I've not been able to find much information on the problem.  It seems that some people mentioned older processors may have a problem (AVX/AVX2 flags being the culprit?), though admittedly I didn't quite understand the connections.

Problem: Can I get some help understanding this error, and if possible, a potential solution?

**Current setup:**

- WSL2
- VSCODE (v. 1.49.0)
- Jupyter-client (v. 6.1.7)
- Jupyter-core (v. 4.6.3)
- FAISS-cpu (v. 1.6.3)
- Numpy (v. 1.19.2)
- Older machine (AMD FX-8350 with 16GB RAM)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that runs across this error, the problem (in my case) was that my CPU was old enough that it doesn't support AVX2.  To determine this, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480071/how-to-tell-if-a-linux-machine-supports-avx-avx2-instructions) SO post.

Once I ran the code in Colab or on a newer machine, all was well.