# Mysterious crash with OpenMP and AVX2 vector intrinsics

Tags: c++, openmp, simd, avx2

I have the following two functions:

```
void bfm(const Parameters& p, int& idx, Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd> bfFrame,
         const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<short int, -1, -1>>& SIG) {

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < p.nPoints; i++) {
        Eigen::VectorXd idxt(p.numEl);     
        int col = i / p.szZ;
        int row = i % p.szZ;
        calcIDXT(p,p.xCoord(col),p.zCoord(row),idx,idxt);// Calculate delay indices
        calcPoint(p,idxt,SIG,bfFrame(row,col));
    }
    
}
```

and:

```
void calcPoint(const Parameters& p, const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& idxt,
               const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<short int, -1, -1>>& SIG,
               double& bfVal) {
    Eigen::VectorXd bfVec = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(p.nc);
    for (int j = 0; j < p.nc; j+=4) {
        __m256d res = linearAVX( (const double*) (idxt.data()+j));//, (const int16_t*) (SIG.data() + j * p.szRF),p.szRF);
        _mm256_storeu_pd(bfVec.data()+j,_mm256_loadu_pd( idxt.data() + j ));
    }
    bfVal = bfVec.sum();
}
```

Right now, the function linearAVX essentially only calls _mm256_loadu_pd( idxt.data() + j) and returns that. The rest of the function is commented out. The casting in the parameters for linearAVX is also redundant (I think) and placed there for debugging purposes.

For some reason, this code compiles fine but crashes at runtime. I can avoid a crash if I comment out the call to linearAVX or I can avoid a crash if I comment out the #pragma omp line. What about linearAVX is not thread safe?

linearAVX code:

```
// Perform linear interpolation using AVX instructions.
//      pIndex  - pointer to value in idxt array
//      pRFCol  - pointer to first channel of RF data
//      N       - number of elements in a single RF channel
__m256d linearAVX( const double* pIndex)//, const int16_t* pRFCol, int N)
{
    // Load 4 idxt values
    __m256d idxt = _mm256_loadu_pd( pIndex );
    
    // Compute idxf and idxd values
//     __m256d idxf = _mm256_floor_pd( idxt );
//     __m256d idxd = _mm256_sub_pd( idxt, idxf );
// 
//     // Compute s1...sN
//     __m256d s1 = _mm256_sub_pd( _mm256_set1_pd( 1.0 ), idxd ); // Note, s2 = idxd for linear interp
    
//     // Gather RF values
//     int base_addr = static_cast<int>(*pIndex);
//     __m128i vindex = _mm_set_epi32(0,N-base_addr,2*N-base_addr,3*N-base_addr);        // NOTE: CHECK THAT THIS IS CORRECT WAY TO PASS VALUES
//     __m128i rfVals = _mm_i32gather_epi32( (const int*) (base_addr + pRFCol),vindex,2);
// 
//     // Upconvert, shuffle and separate
//     __m256i rfUpconv = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(rfVals);
//     __m256i rfShuf = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(_mm256_shuffle_epi32(rfUpconv,216),216); // 216 = 0b11011000 in binary, 0xD8 in Hex. See documentation
//     // Additional note: using _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32 may be faster? Experiment with this and find out later
// 
//     __m256d rf1 = _mm256_cvtepi32_pd(_mm256_extracti128_si256(rfShuf,0));
//     __m256d rf2 = _mm256_cvtepi32_pd(_mm256_extracti128_si256(rfShuf,1));
// 
//     // Multiply coeffs and sum to get result
//     __m256d result = _mm256_add_pd(_mm256_mul_pd(rf1,s1),_mm256_mul_pd(rf2,idxd));
// 
//     return result;
    
    return idxt;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your CPU supports AVX?  Or if running in a VM, is it passing through AVX to the guest?  If that's the problem, it's unrelated to OpenMP and would happen in a trivial single-threaded test program.

Comment: My processor according to dxdiag is: Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2680 v3. According to this link: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/81908/intel-xeon-processor-e52680-v3-30m-cache-2-50-ghz/specifications.html it should

Comment: To clarify, if I comment out the openmp line and only the openmp line, it also still compiles and runs

Comment: Your CPU supports AVX, so the question is whether you're running in a VM that hides that in CPUID.  If so, the OS won't enable AVX via control registers.  When you say it doesn't crash without OpenMP, could that just be the compiler optimizing away all the AVX instructions when there's no real work?  Like just turning the copy loop into a call to memcpy?

Comment: What instruction actually faults?  Use a debugger to check.  If it's not an AVX instruction, maybe you're writing outside the bounds of where you should be.  I see your loop bound is `j < p.nc` rather than `j < p.nc-3`, so that's not safe if `p.nc` isn't a multiple of 4.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm writing and compiling all of this from matlab using the mex command. I haven't familiarized myself with linux, VMs or typical debugging tools. P.nc is also guaranteed to be a multiple of 4.

Comment: Is `p.nc` a multiple of 4?  If not, your `_mm256_storeu_pd` is writing off the end of valid memory.

Comment: Oh, you're running on Linux?  I assumed Windows from your dxdiag.  On Linux, `grep -o 'avx[^ ]*' /proc/cpuinfo` ([How to tell if a Linux machine supports AVX/AVX2 instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37480071)) to rule out the possibility of a VM being the problem.  (If you're not running in a VM in the first place, then that won't be the problem, but that's a way to be sure.)  I'm not recommending a VM!

Comment: I am not running on linux. I'm running on windows.

Comment: WTF?  Why did you mention Linux, then?  It's not the only OS that has debuggers or VMs!  Attach a debugger to your process before doing the thing that crashes, then run and see what instruction faults.

Comment: Is `p.nc == idxt.size()` (or `<=`)? Can you provide a [mre] (including a `main` function which calls your method)?

Comment: What am I missing? Where is the `res` used that comes from the (probably) offending function?